# Is it possible to use only one VkCommandBuffer for all VkFramebuffer

Tags: vulkan

When i read the Vulkan examples code. It has 2 or 3 SwapchainImageResources. And each SwapchainImageResources has a framebuffer. then for each VkFramebuffer, the examples code create a VkCommandBuffer.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: sorry, the question updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the jobs `VkCommandBuffer` has is to determine the `VkFramebuffer` through a *Render Pass instance* (i.e. `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`).

So: no. Unless you count re-recording the same `VkCommandBuffer` on demand, when you need to change the `VkFramebuffer`.

One of the charms of Vulkan is it tries to create solid state objects, and rarely introduces moving parts. It helps reasoning about Vulkan (especially in multi-threaded environment, and also possibly helps in making the drivers more simple) at the cost of sometimes having to write more code (i.e. destroy and create anew an object one only needs to modify). It requires some getting used to...